# Can someone help me understand how async + await + useEffect work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect

I have a React app built with the Minimal template and I'm trying to follow along with one of their tutorials, in order to create a Redux slice that feeds some data to a custom component. The data itself is collected from Firebase. Below is my code:

**firebase.js - helper**

```
export function getDocuments(col) {
    const colRef = collection(db, col);
    const q = query(colRef, where('uid', '==', auth.currentUser.uid));

    getDocs(q).then((snap) => {
        const data = snap.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }));
        return data;
    });
   // return [1,2,3]
}
```

**product.js - Redux slice**

```
export function getProducts() {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(slice.actions.startLoading());
        try {
            const products = await getDocuments('products');
            dispatch(slice.actions.getProductsSuccess(products));
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(slice.actions.hasError(error));
        }
    };
}
```

**ProductList.js - component**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { products } = useSelector((state) => state.client);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProducts());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (products.length) {
        // setTableData(products);
    }
}, [products]);
```

If I console log `data` in the helper function (*firebase.js*), I get the values I expect, once the promise is resolved/fulfilled. However, if I console.log `clients` in the **product.js** slice or later in the component, I get `undefined`.
I assume my problem is not being able to understand how async + await + useEffect work together in order to fix this. My assumption is that I am trying to access the value before the promise is resolved and therefore before the helper function returns it. I confirmed that by returning a simple array `[1, 2, 3]` in my helper function as a test.

I think I am missing something fundamental here (I am not very experienced with React and JS in general and still learning things on the go). Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am going to read it through to get a better understanding of the different methods - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `await` you can await the fulfillment or rejection of a promise, but your `getDocuments` Function does not return a promise. Change the last line of the function to the following:

```
return getDocs(q).then((snap) => {
    const data = snap.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }));
    return data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Async** and **Await** are no different in `React` than in plain `JavaScript`:
When the await keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete. await can only be used inside an async method

**useEffect()**:
By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after rendering. This function will run every time the component is re-rendered.